# How can I use 'last' with order condition within 'If statement'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was trying to code it like this.
What's wrong with this?

```
def topic_button(community)
    if !community.topics.order("last_active_at DESC").last.nil? && community.topics.order("last_active_at DESC").last.last_active_at.to_date == Date.current.to_date
        'posted today'
    else
        'no post today'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `today?` method:

```
def topic_button(community)
  last_post = community.topics.order('last_active_at DESC').last
  if last_post && last_post.last_active_at.today?
    'posted today'
  else
    'no post today'
  end
end
```

Comment: In few communities, it gets nil when doing `last_post_time = community.community_topics.order('last_active_at DESC').last.last_active_at`

Comment: Also, DESC will mean that most recent topics will come first. You may want to change `last` to `first` depending on what your application is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if  @community.topics.last_active_at == Date.current.to_date
        puts "posted today"
 else
        puts "no post today"
 end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks:) but the problem is last_active_at is not in order. last_active_at will be updated when if it's commented by someone:(

Answer (score 1):

You should really just be doing the query once:

```
topic = community.topics.order("last_active_at DESC").last

if topic && topic.last_active_at.to_date == Date.current.to_date
   puts "posted today"
else
  puts "no post today"
end
```